# schedule jobs with play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

My project uses play framework 2.3 and needs to calculate the real time price of the user's items listed in the market every 10 minutes(The item's price changes according to the number of sales kind of like stocks). I used actor to do that. However, i have a questions

How to start the job when the project starts and I can also stop the job in the code?

```
 Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(0.microseconds, 10.minutes, tickActor, "job")

package job.scheduledJobs

import akka.actor.Actor


class JobModule extends Actor {
   override def preStart() {
   println("makeRealTimePrice Job start!!")
}

override def receive: Receive = {
    case "job" =>
    //calculate price
    case _ => Unit
}
}


class TradingHandler(override implicit val env: 
RuntimeEnvironment[SystemUser]) extends 
securesocial.core.SecureSocial[SystemUser] with CookieLang {
def job() = Action {
    implicit request =>
       val tickActor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props(new JobModule))
       val cancellable1 = Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(0.microseconds, 10.minutes, tickActor, "job")
      Ok("success")
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you're looking for [the Global object](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaGlobal) wherein you can hook into the application start and stop events to trigger things. From what I understand, you'd need to have a value inside of Global that stores the `Cancellable` and the `onStop` callback can cancel it on application stop.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have two possibilities:

- Use [web socket](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWebSockets)  - so you instantiate just one Actor per user and run scheduler for each actor.
- Make your controller a singleton and instantiate actor in that singleton.

Akka actors are cheap to create so I believe you should instantiate one actor per client instead of one actor for all clients.